# Getting the value from Swift class to Objective-C class

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I'm to use Swift class in my Objective-C Application. And I successfully integrate the swift class in my app and I can access the class also, But Swift class didn't return a value

Am using this library

https://github.com/ytakzk/Fusuma

the problem while selecting image from the gallery it should return the image but it didn't

here is a code :

```
   @IBAction func doneButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {

    let view = albumView.imageCropView

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size, true, 0)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -albumView.imageCropView.contentOffset.x, -albumView.imageCropView.contentOffset.y)
    view.layer.renderInContext(context!)
    let image : UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    print(image)

    delegate?.fusumaImageSelected(image)
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
    self.delegate?.fusumaDismissedWithImage?(image)
    })
}
```

The same code is working good in Swift application.

Comment: How did you implemented the delegate method?

Comment: all delegate methods were available in the swift class , i just import the swift class in my objective c class and using it

Comment: The image is returned through the delegate. Did you set it? Did you implement the delegate method of Fosumadelegate Protocol `fusumaDismissedWithImage:` or `fusumaImageSelected:`?

Comment: yes that i have implemented in my objective c class           - (void)fusumaImageSelected:(UIImage * _Nonnull)image{
    NSLog(@"Image %@",image);
}

Comment: but its not called

Comment: Did you set the delegate? `self.fusumaImageObject.delegate = self` (or something like that).

Comment: yes like this am accessing the class  FusumaViewController *SwiftView = [[FusumaViewController alloc]init];
    SwiftView.delegate = self;
    SwiftView =  [[FusumaViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FusumaViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:SwiftView animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: Double init? Why ? The second one is erasing the delegate setting.

Comment: oh then how do i present the class

Comment: `FusumaViewController *SwiftView = [[FusumaViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FusumaViewController" bundle:nil]; SwiftView.delegate = self;[self.navigationController presentViewController:SwiftView animated:YES completion:nil];` ?

Comment: thanks for your response

Comment: i did the same but fusumaClosed method only calling other methods not calling

Comment: this method is calling - (void)fusumaImageSelected:(UIImage * _Nonnull)image{
but it ddin't return the image not even print the log NSLog(@"MethodCalled");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112871/discussion-between-vignesh-and-larme).

Answer (score 0):

Ok Then lets first explain why its not working with Objective-C and its only working with Swift, the issue is the framework is build to be compatible with Swift only and not so far for Objective-C use, meaning the delegate is not exposed in the headers of the framework for Objective-C for example.

There is a work around for your app lets start with adding the library as a pod, set the Swift Language to 4.1 in Build settings (for the framework), using Xcode 9.4.1:

```
use_frameworks!
pod 'Fusuma', :git => 'https://github.com/ytakzk/Fusuma.git', :branch => 'master'
```

Now Create a Swift file called `FusumaExtention.swift` and add the following code in it, **Note that if its the first time you are adding a Swift file it will ask you to Create a header in Xcode then Say YES**, the ViewController is your Objective-C class:

```
import UIKit
import Fusuma

extension ViewController:FusumaDelegate {

    public func fusumaImageSelected(_ image: UIImage, source: FusumaMode) {
        // pass the selected image to your view controller method
        self.fusumaImageSelected(image)

    }

    public func fusumaMultipleImageSelected(_ images: [UIImage], source: FusumaMode) {

    }

    public func fusumaVideoCompleted(withFileURL fileURL: URL) {

    }

    public func fusumaCameraRollUnauthorized() {

    }

    func setDelegateToSelf(FusumaVC:FusumaViewController){

        FusumaVC.delegate = self

    }

}
```

Now you may find a complier error to say that it cant find the ViewController which is your Objective-C class, you will need to import it into the `ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h` file as the following :

```
#import "ViewController.h"
```

Now Finally we can go back to the Objective-C class "ViewController.h" and import the following lines:

```
#import <Fusuma/Fusuma-Swift.h>
#import <Fusuma/Fusuma-umbrella.h>
```

Then add the following method inside the interface as the following, this method will be called when the image is selected:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

-(void)fusumaImageSelected:(UIImage *)image;

@end
```

Now go back to your `ViewController.m` and import the following line which makes the extension that we created earlier available to objective-c to be able to set the delegate for fusuma:

```
#import <ProjectName-Swift.h>
```

Then lets say you use the following method to present from your Objective-C Class:

```
- (IBAction)showController:(id)sender {

    FusumaViewController *fusuma = [[FusumaViewController alloc] init];
    [self setDelegateToSelfWithFusumaVC:fusuma];
    [self presentViewController:fusuma animated:true completion:nil];

}
```

Then implement the function that we defined in the header class below it, this method will be called after the image is selected :

```
-(void)fusumaImageSelected:(UIImage *)image{

    // do what ever you want with selected image.

}
```

This should work, its already tested.

[Sample project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fnfaT6b0OxfnpUC6-jmtxx7Ouuzmyzbh/view?usp=sharing)